# how to convert unicode to german umlauts with sql query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, unicode, diacritics

I have a SQL table that stores values entered by the user. After users entered German umlauts, it was saved in SQL as follows: `m&#252;ssen`, `&#220;ben` and much more.
Now I need a SQL Query that includes all columns `&#252;` replaced with `ü`.

Can someone help me with the SQL query?

Comment: Have you fixed your application layer first? If you don't, then the data is going to continue to be malformed when it is updated and inserted.

Comment: What is the actual column data type and collation?

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be your solution:

```
UPDATE db.tablename 
SET fieldname = REPLACE(fieldname, '&#252;', 'ü')
WHERE fieldname LIKE '%&#252;%';
```

Comment: Though if the column is nvarchar I would definitely prefix all of those string literals with `N'an N prefix'` just to be safe.

Comment: as I unfortunately did not understand, sorry

Comment: @tristan did you have experience with mysql? maybe its better if you do some tutorials and read little bit of the mysql documentation bevor you are using sql queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from [lptr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr) comment, which was a link to a DB Fiddle. I have posted this an answer to preserve it's usefulness, as comments can be deleted at any time.

Here they use makes use of the `xml` data type to implicitly convert back the value to what it should be:

> ```sql
> select *, cast(t.col as xml).value('.', 'nvarchar(50)')
> from
> (
> values(N'm&#252;ssen'), (N'&#220;ben')
> ) as t(col);
> ```
>
> [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ebbb37d85ef79048dbf8d5975883d0b2)

You may, however, find better performance using `(./text())[1]` instead of just `.`.

Comment: It's not my code, @tristan , but why do you say it's not dynamic? It would handle any escaped characters. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8825605169ff8e07188f724aca6b59dd)

Comment: That's the sample data *you* gave, @tristan ... So that was the sample data that was used by lptr; they aren't going to guess your data. Test it and find out with more data.

Comment: Tested with your new example too, @tristan : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9b0cc3eb9167b2ff558dbbb2bdf6fcc)

Comment: This is the real answer, was thinking of something along these lines. `text()[1]` is shorter than `(./text())[1]` by the way, `.` is the default context node anyway so is not needed